# What is $0!$ in base $4$?

Tags: factorial

In base $10$ we have  $0!=1$; however, I am not sure if this applies to different bases. In general, what is the 'rule' for factorials in different bases?

Comment: Why would the definition of the factorial depend on the base?

Comment: Factorial has nothing to do with bases.  Bases are merely notation we use to notate and use symbols for quantities.  Multiplication, addition, exponents, factorial, etc.  would be the same whatever symbols, notation, or language we use.  We could use roman numberals or sumerian cuneiforms and factorials would still be the same.

Comment: The only rule for bases about factorials that I know if is about counting the number of zeros at the end of the base ten representation based on how may factors of 5 and powers of 5 there are.  For base 4 that obviously is different and it'd be a matter of counting the number of factors of 2 and powers of 2.  But as to what n! *is*.  $n! = \prod_{k=1}^n k$ and that will be the same thing no matter what base one uses.  Base only reflects what symbols we use to write the digits as.

Answer (score 5):

Having said that $0_{10}!=1_{10}$, you can just convert the $0$ and $1$ to base $4$.  What do you get?  $13_4$ and $7_{10}$ are different names for the same number.

Answer (score 5):

Once $(1)_{10}=(1)_4$ then $(0!)_4=1$

The definition of factorial is the same for all bases. The only difference is the representation of the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Changing a base does not change the value of an expression.  The number $16_7 = 13_{10}$ are both the same number even though they are written differently.  $16_7$ is still a prime number and pile of thirteen apples isn't going to magically turn into something else just because you lost three fingers.

$16_7! = 16_7*15_7*14_7*13_7*12_7*11_7*10_7*6*5*4*3*2*1$

and $13! = 13*12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1$

and $XIII! = XIII*XII*XI*X*IX**VIII*VII*VI*V*IV*III*II*I$

are all the same *thing*.

So $0! = 1$.  Period.  So $0_b! = 1_b$ no matter what base.

... or less trivial:

$7_{10} = 10_7 = 11_6 = 12_5 = 13_4$

And $7_{10}! = 7*6*.... *2*1 = 5040_{10}$

$10_7 = 10_7*6*5*4*3*2*1 = 20460_7$

$11_6 = 11_6*10_6*5*4*3*2*1 = 35200_6$

$12_5 = 12_5*11_5*10_5*4*3*2*1 =  130130_5$

$13_4 = 13_4*12_4*11_4*10_4*3*2*1 = 1032300_4$

Which are all the exact same number, namely then number $\prod_{k=1}^{7_{10}} k$.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the 'rule' for factorials in different bases?

There isn't one.  The factorial is just repeated multiplication, so perhaps the best way to proceed in general is to multiply in base 10 and then convert the result.  Since $0! = 1$ in base 10, and $1_{10} = 1_4$, then $0!$ is still 1 in base 4.  For a slightly less trivial example, let's consider $3!$ in base 4.  It's $3 \cdot 2 = 6 = 1 \cdot 4^1 + 2 \cdot 4^0$, so $3! = 12_4$.

Answer (score 0):

In factorials we dont have any base system like we have in number systems.

So $(0!)_4 = 1$

[In combinatorics we have factorial number system. Maybe you looking for this.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system)

Comment: On the one hand this is completely irrelevant and obtuse.  (The the question isn't about the advanced factoradic number system but about basic factorials).  But on the other hand maybe this explains the OP's frankly bizzare misconception that the base of a number system has anything to do with factorials.

Comment: @fleablood I have updated my answer. If still something wrong please let me know.